# Is HDF5 an Appropriate Technology to Store JSON Data?

Tags: json, hdf5

I've inherited some code which makes calls to a web API, and get's a deeply nested (up to eight levels) response.

I've written some code to flatten the structure so that it can be written to .csv files, and a SQL database, for people to consume more easily.

What I'd really like to do though is keep a version of the original response, so that there's a reference of the original structure if I ever want/need it.

I understand that HDF5 is primarily meant to store numerical data. Is there any reason not to use it to dump JSON blobs? It seems a lot easier than setting up a NoSQL database.

Comment: I would not recommend that at all. First of all, if you use variable length strings, your h5 file will be much larger, that you would expect. I was really surprised by this. Second, hdf5 is designed for storing numerical data. For JSON I would recommend MongoDB as it was designed primarily for JSON and it has many features you will appreciate. And running it is very easy. If you use docker than `docker run -d mongo` will do the job. If you don't like docker, than you can set it up with few commands...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decided it was easier to set up a Mongo database.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine.  It sounds like you'd be storing each JSON response as a HDF5 variable length string.  Which is fine, it's just a string to the library.

Do you plan to store each response as a separate dataset?  That may be inefficient if you are talking about >1000's of responses.

Alternatively, you can create a 1-d extensible dataset, and just append to it with each response.